# Magento 2: add classes and icons to homepage widget

Tags: magento-2.1, widgets, widget-instance

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

On the **home page**, I have inserted a "New Products" widget **via the Magento admin**.

[image]

I am using **Font Awesome** and **Bootstrap** in my custom theme and I want to take advantage of those, by adding classes and icons to the product boxes in the image below.

I want those "Add to Cart" to have this code:

```
<button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart btn">
 <span class="hidden">Add to Cart</span>
 <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

The problem is the **HTML editor** in the Magento admin does not offer this possibility and I can't find the *.phtml* template responsible for rendering the widget.

1. What is a viable alternative to what I did so far?
2. Is there an alternative to inserting the "New Products" widget via the Magento admin, that would allow me to edit the widget's HTML as detailed as I wish/need? In other words: can I insert the block *via some template*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override the template file and changes the html in this file

Copy the file from below path

```
 vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml
```

In your theme paste the file to:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml
```

And do changes in this file.

Comment: Your suggestion worked with one amendment" the fi;e I needed to overwrite was `new_default_list.phtml` not `new_grid.phtml`.

Comment: How do I set (bigger) _width_ and _height_ for the product images in the screenshot above?

Comment: You can use below code for resize image

Comment: Where, in what file?

Comment: new_default_list.phtml                    <?php $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFr‌​ame(FALSE)->resize(5‌​00)->getUrl(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" />

Comment: Remove this code <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>

Comment: <?php $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); 
$productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFr‌​ame(FALSE)->resize(5‌​00)->getUrl(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" />

Comment: Replacing `<?php echo $block->getImage($_product, 'side_column_widget_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>` with your code in `new_default_list.phtml` produces no cgange. Any dashboard alternative? :)

Comment: Have you added this ? <img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" />

Comment: I have `<a class="product-item-photo" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                            <?php echo $block->getImage($_product, 'side_column_widget_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
                        </a>`. ti is all I have. What shall I replace it with?

Comment: Shall I ask a _new question_, to be more clear?

Comment: Just replace below code  <?php echo $block->getImage($_product, 'side_column_widget_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: <?php $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); 
$productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFr‌​ame(FALSE)->resize(5‌​00)->getUrl(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

You can add such icons with help of CSS, you just need to pass the content code in css; below is an example

What is a viable alternative to what I did so far?

**You can use icons in CSS, just need to get the class/id and apply the content 
  code in CSS. http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/**

Is there an alternative to inserting the "New Products" widget via the Magento admin, that would allow me to edit the widget's HTML as detailed as I wish/need?

**Most of the design customization you can do with the help of CSS, rest you need to create another template to render here.**

Comment: I have already included Font Awesome in some template files. I would like to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have inserted widget from admin. 
You can change widget template, like I have changed in following code from **new_grid.phtml to custom_new_grid.phtml**

```
<p>{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="all_products" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/new/content/custom_new_grid.phtml"}}</p>
```

and created new template file custom_new_grid.phtml in my custom theme. 
In this custom file you can add your own classes.

Comment: Great stuff! One question:  In what directory of my theme precisely shall I put my (not yet created) `custom_new_products.phtml` file?

Comment: You can create new custom template inside app/design/frontend/NameSpace/custom-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/

Comment: _NameSpace_ is company name, right?

Comment: Also, being really new to Magento, Whare can I find a good example  `custom_products_template.phtml` (generic file name)?

Comment: Yes, you can choose your company name as namespace.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you can search on internet on how to create custom templates and create new theme and override templates in Magento2, I am sure you will find many helpful articles. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html may help you.

Comment: Is `type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget"` generally applicable, or just for you? Can I use it as it _is_?

Comment: Yes, it is general.