# Magento 2: insert a "Bestsellers" widget via the Magento admin

Tags: widget, best-seller

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

On the **home page**, I want to insert a "Bestsellers" widget **via the Magento admin**, like the one below:

[image]

By default, Magento only offers the possibility to insert a "New products" widget.

What is the best approach to insert a "Bestsellers" widget too?

UPDATE: I have installed the module, run the tasks:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Anshu_Bestsellerwidget
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

The module does not show in the frontend and the background it looks like this:

[image]

What is wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created something similar using following code.

**app/code/Anshu/Bestsellerwidget/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Bestsellerwidget',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Bestsellerwidget/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Bestsellerwidget" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Bestsellerwidget/etc/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="anshu_bestsellerwidget" class="Anshu\Bestsellerwidget\Block\Product\Widget\BestsellerWidget" ttl="86400">
        <label translate="true">Bestseller Products List</label>
        <description translate="true">List of Best Selling Products</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="productcount" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="1" >
                <label translate="true">Product Count</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="imagewidth" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="2" >
                <label translate="true">Image Width</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="imageheight" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="3" >
                <label translate="true">Image Height</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Cache Lifetime (Seconds)</label>
                <description translate="true">86400 by default, if not set. To refresh instantly, clear the Blocks HTML Output cache.</description>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Bestsellerwidget/Block/Product/Widget/BestsellerWidget.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Bestsellerwidget\Block\Product\Widget;

/**
 * Best Seller products widget
 */
class BestsellerWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'bestsellerproduct.phtml';

    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;
    const DEFAULT_IMAGE_WIDTH = 150;
    const DEFAULT_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 150;
    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;
    protected $_resourceFactory;
    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Image helper
     *
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $_imageHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    protected $_cartHelper;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $resourceFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\Grouped\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Helper\Data $reportsData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_resourceFactory = $resourceFactory;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_reportsData = $reportsData;
        $this->_imageHelper = $context->getImageHelper();
        $this->_cartHelper = $context->getCartHelper();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Image helper Object
     */
    public function imageHelperObj(){
        return $this->_imageHelper;
    }
    /**
     * get featured product collection
     */
    public function getBestsellerProduct(){
        $limit = $this->getProductLimit();

        $resourceCollection = $this->_resourceFactory->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection');
        $resourceCollection->setPageSize($limit);
        return $resourceCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get the configured limit of products
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductLimit() {
        if($this->getData('productcount')==''){
            return DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->getData('productcount');
    }
    /**
     * Get the widht of product image
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductimagewidth() {
        if($this->getData('imagewidth')==''){
            return DEFAULT_IMAGE_WIDTH;
        }
        return $this->getData('imagewidth');
    }
    /**
     * Get the height of product image
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductimageheight() {
        if($this->getData('imageheight')==''){
            return DEFAULT_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
        }
        return $this->getData('imageheight');
    }
    /**
     * Get the add to cart url
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = [])
    {
        return $this->_cartHelper->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }
    /**
     * Return HTML block with price
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $priceType
     * @param string $renderZone
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function getProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $priceType = null,
        $renderZone = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if (!isset($arguments['zone'])) {
            $arguments['zone'] = $renderZone;
        }
        $arguments['zone'] = isset($arguments['zone'])
            ? $arguments['zone']
            : $renderZone;
        $arguments['price_id'] = isset($arguments['price_id'])
            ? $arguments['price_id']
            : 'old-price-' . $product->getId() . '-' . $priceType;
        $arguments['include_container'] = isset($arguments['include_container'])
            ? $arguments['include_container']
            : true;
        $arguments['display_minimal_price'] = isset($arguments['display_minimal_price'])
            ? $arguments['display_minimal_price']
            : true;
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                $arguments
            );
        }
        return $price;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Bestsellerwidget/view/frontend/templates/bestsellerproduct.phtml**

```
<?php
if ($exist = ($this->getBestsellerProduct() && $this->getBestsellerProduct()->getPageSize())) {
    $fet_prodcollection = $this->getBestsellerProduct();
    $productcount = $this->getProductLimit();
    $imagewidth = $this->getProductimagewidth();
    $imageheight = $this->getProductimageheight();
    $mode = 'grid';
    $title = __('Bestseller Products');
    $type = 'widget-bestseller-grid';
    $image = 'bestseller_products_content_widget_grid';
}
?>

<?php if ($exist) { ?>
<div class="block widget block-bestseller-products <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="2"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title; ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
        <div class="products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
            <ol class="product-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $type; ?>">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($fet_prodcollection as $item):

                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
                    ?>

                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                    <div class="product-item-info">
                        <?php

                        $image_url = $block->imageHelperObj()->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')
                            ->setImageFile($_product->getFile())
                            ->resize($imagewidth,$imageheight)
                            ->getUrl();

                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                            <img src="<?php echo  $image_url;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-item-details">
                            <strong class="product-item-name">
                                <a title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>"
                                   href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                                   class="product-item-link">
                                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?php
                            echo $this->getProductPriceHtml($_product, $type);
                            ?>

                            <div class="product-item-actions">

                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_product)): ?>
                                            <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                    data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl":{"url":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"}}'
                                                    type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <?php
                                            $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                            $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_product), ['product' => $_product->getId()]);
                                            ?>
                                            <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                    data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>'
                                                    type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>


                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo($iterator == count($fet_prodcollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have taken reference from https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-best-seller

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Is that an entire _module_ you made?

Comment: How would you adapt [this solution](https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/) to Magento 2.1.7?

Comment: You can customize above code/module according to your requirement

Comment: The article you have shared is for Magento1 and will not work in Magento2

Comment: I understand, but I am trying, if possible, to put as _few_ lines of custom code in the application as possible. Magento being full of code already. Can I stay closer to a simple solution, like [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199940/magento-2-add-classes-and-icons-to-homepage-widget)? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. You are awesome! Is there a reason not to use the one you have taken the reference from? Is it old?

Comment: You can use the referenced one but check the functionality and make changes according to your requirement.

Comment: I want to use _your_ module. I was asking if there are any reasons to use one over the other.

Comment: You can use any one, it is your choice.

Comment: Look like there is a problem with the Anusha module. I have updated the question.

Comment: Refresh the report statistics and try again.

Comment: Where can I find the report statistics?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69374/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-anshu-mishra).

Comment: @RazvanZamfir http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports.html will help you.

Comment: I did all that, with no effect...

Comment: `<ol class="product-items widget-bestseller-grid"> </ol>` is empty. Could something be wrong with your module?

Comment: There is a bug in this module: every product box is linked to _the same_ single product. How can I fix that?

Comment: You are very knowledgeable of Magento. Please help me with the issue **[Assign all products in a category to all it's ancestor categories programmatically, in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208650/assign-all-products-in-a-category-to-all-its-ancestor-categories-programmatical)**. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnshuMishra, this code work for config products also?

Comment: @jafarpinjar It should work but I am not sure as it is quite old code. You can try and optimize the code to make it work. it is just a sample.

Comment: should use  return self::DEFAULT_IMAGE_HEIGHT; instead of  return DEFAULT_IMAGE_HEIGHT;


Good work it save my time

Comment: @AnshuMishra, can you please add and example on how to use your widget and what we should know?